# What does the word "them" signify here?

Tags: meaning-in-context, pronouns, ambiguity

Here is a sentence from a schedule planner app:

> In the app, you can easily group to-dos into projects and drag tasks within
>   and between them.

I am not sure if the word "them" is used here for "to-dos" or "projects."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would assume *them* refers to *projects*, because *to-dos* and *tasks* are pretty much synonymous. But the language here is somewhat confusing and ambiguous, as you can tell. Maybe it would be better understood if written this way:

> In the app, you can easily group to-dos into projects and drag them within and between projects.

Comment: I agree with you. I have a query. In my opinion, the word "group" simply means "add" here. Am I correct?

Comment: @curious *group* essentially means “combine”. So you get a project as the result of combining to-dos. You can add to-dos to an existing project.

Comment: Looks like you asked this question here also https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/210096/what-does-the-phrase-group-into-mean-here