# What does the phrase "group into" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrases

Here is a sentence from a schedule planner app:

> In the app, you can easily **group to-dos into** projects and drag tasks within
>   and between them.

I am not sure if the word "group into" is used in the sense of "add" here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Group" is both a noun and a verb. As a noun, it is a collection of something. As a verb, it means the action of putting things into groups. So, we can "*put things into groups*" (so the collection is *called* "a group"), or we can "*group things into...*" and name the collection something else entirely.

In your example, the verb "group" is being used. The individual items are "to-dos", and the name of the groups is "projects".

It is not exactly synonymous with "adding", however, if a group already exists then yes you can "add" something to it. In your example though, it seems to be talking about *creating* new groups of things, so "grouping" is the right verb.